# Footer is floating up

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have single page structure as follows. 
When Home or Orders or About links are clicked - the page scrolls to show that section on the page:

```
<body style="height: 100%;">
    ...
    <header id="home">
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#home">Home</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#orders">Orders</a></li> 
        <li class="scroll"><a href="#about">About</a></li>    
    </header>

    <section id="orders" style="min-height:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFFFAA;">
        ...
    </section>

    <section id="about" style="min-height:100%; height:100%; background-color:#FFFFBB;">
        ...
    </section>

    <footer id="footer" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;width:100%;">
        ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

The footer shows up correctly on first load, when only the header section is visible. But when Orders link is clicked, the footer just floats up along with header section, as if it is part of header section.

Comment: display:inline-block;

Comment: Did you try to use pixels instead of using percents in height?

Comment: Why would anyone vote this question for 'Close'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `position: fixed`:

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
footer {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<header id="home">
  <li class="scroll"><a href="#home">Home</a>

  </li>
  <li class="scroll"><a href="#orders">Orders</a>

  </li>
  <li class="scroll"><a href="#about">About</a>

  </li>
</header>
<section id="orders" style="min-height:500px; background-color:#FFFFAA;">
  <h2>Orders</h2>

</section>
<section id="about" style="min-height:500px; background-color:#FFFFBB;">
  <h2>About</h2>

</section>
<footer id="footer" style="position: fixed; bottom:0;width:100%;">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: isherwood> Perfect. Works!